# How to get annotation in Google diffchart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Im using diff chart from google api for bar chart in my application. I need to get the annotation for my diff chart(bar). But im getting error in this code. Please help me to get the annotation in diffchart. 
The code i've used is given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", '1.1', {packages: ['corechart']});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var oldData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Name', 'Popularity'],
                    ['Cesar', 2000],
                    ['Rachel', 4200],
                    ['Patrick', 2900],
                    ['Eric', 8200]
                ]);

                var newData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Name', 'Popularity', {role: 'annotation'}],
                    ['Cesar', 370, 'df'],
                    ['Rachel', 600, 'ff'],
                    ['Patrick', 700, 'dfg'],
                    ['Eric', 1500, 'dsf'],
                ]);

                var colChartBefore = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('colchart_before'));
                var colChartAfter = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('colchart_after'));
                var colChartDiff = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('colchart_diff'));
                var barChartDiff = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_diff'));

                var options = {legend: {position: 'top'}, diff: {newData: {widthFactor: 1}}};

                colChartBefore.draw(oldData, options);
                colChartAfter.draw(newData, options);

                var diffData = colChartDiff.computeDiff(oldData, newData);
                colChartDiff.draw(diffData, options);
                barChartDiff.draw(diffData, options);
            }
        </script>

        <span id='colchart_before' style='width: 450px; height: 250px; display: inline-block'></span>
        <span id='colchart_after' style='width: 450px; height: 250px; display: inline-block'></span>
        <span id='colchart_diff' style='width: 450px; height: 250px; display: inline-block'></span>
        <span id='barchart_diff' style='width: 450px; height: 250px; display: inline-block'></span>
```

I've referred this code from this [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/diffchart)

Comment: After experimenting with annotations and DiffCharts, I have come to the conclusion that annotations are either unsupported on DiffCharts, or they are broken.  Either way, they need to be supported, so I filed a bug report on this here: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1455.  You can "star" the issue to get updates.